# Python: Creating multiple text files from a list of article titles

Tags: python

I have a long list of article titles stored in a text file, and I would like to loop through the list, creating text files, each one titled according to the list.

So inside C:/articles.txt I have...

Monday 
Tuesday 
Wednesday 
Thursday 
etc...

and I would like text files generated titled...

Monday.txt
Tuesday.txt
etc...

The actual filename are not days of the week, but will be several thousand translated documents which I am passing through Google's translate API, so I guess the text will need to be unicode, will this cause a problem?

so far I have:

```
titles = open("C:/titles.txt",'r')

for lines in titles:       
    output = open((lines)+'.txt','w')
    output.write(lines.strip('\n'))
    output.close()

titles.close()
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/createarticle.py", line 5, in <module>
output = open((lines)+'.txt','w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'Monday\n.txt'
```

I have tried opening the file with repr(lines) and str(lines) but no joy...I am a little lost!

Comment: Wouldn't `for line in titles:` or even `for title in titles:` be a more descriptive variable name? You're only getting one line/title at a time, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing just on the specific error, your filenames have a "\n" embedded within them. Try replacing `(lines)+'.txt'` with `lines.strip() + '.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove \n (new line character) from file name using `lines.strip()`.

```
output = open((lines.strip())+'.txt','w')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a new line symbol on the end of every line "\n". You have to strip that because the name becomes "Monday\n.txt"  and  "\" is invalid for file name.

Comment: The backslash is not actually part of the filename -- the newline is part of the filename. I don't know if newline is valid in a windows filename, but both backslash and newline are valid filename characters on *nix.

Answer (score 1):

So far, it seems that you are creating a file with a newline in its name (so something like `Monday\n.txt`. You need to strip() the name of the file before you add the .txt extension, like this:

```
for lines in titles.readlines():
    output = open((lines.strip())+'.txt','w')
    (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the lines and strip "n" using list comprehension:

```
titles = [t.strip("\n") for t in open("/etc/passwd").readlines()]
```